# RuntimeError: :json is not registered on Faraday::Request

Tags: ruby, rspec, faraday

I am fairly new to ruby and I am trying to execute a spec and I receive this error:

> RuntimeError:
>              :json is not registered on Faraday::Request

I am trying to use this gem:  https://github.com/Chicago/windy

Mac OS X 10.7.4
Ruby 1.9.3, using RVM

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've just run into this when upgrading Faraday. The json request middleware was removed from Faraday in 0.8. It is now in the `faraday_middleware` gem. You should `gem install faraday_middleware` and require it in the file that creates the Faraday object.

See https://github.com/lostisland/faraday_middleware/wiki/Changes-0.8

Comment: wasn't working for me until I realized I had skipped the *'require it in the file that creates the Faraday object'* part.